# Small program to get binary diff offset between two small files

Tags: file, go

Trivial utility program meant to go through the list of (small) files and report file offset of the first difference between them. The goal of the code is simplicity.

Any recommendations are useful. Be brutal. I'm collecting go experience :)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        fmt.Println("expecting at least 2 arguments")
        return
    }

    nfi := len(os.Args) - 1

    bufs := make([][]byte, nfi)

    // read in the files
    for i, fn := range os.Args[1:] {
        fi, err := os.Open(fn)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error opening file %s: %v", fn, err)
            return
        }
        defer fi.Close()

        bufs[i], err = ioutil.ReadAll(fi)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error reading from file %s: %v", fn, err)
        }
    }

    // get a minimum len of all the buffers
    min := len(bufs[0])
    for _, b := range bufs[1:] {
        l := len(b)
        if l < min {
            min = l
        }
    }

    // compare values one by one
    for i := 0; i < min; i++ { // loop over offset

        v := bufs[0][i]            // a byte from first file
        for j := 1; j < nfi; j++ { // loop over the rest of files
            if v != bufs[j][i] {
                fmt.Printf("first difference at offset %d = 0x%x\n", i, i)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("no differences found")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand your program better, I cleaned up up your code.

`diff.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    files := os.Args[1:]
    if len(files) < 2 {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "expecting at least 2 files")
        return
    }

    bufs := make([][]byte, len(files))
    for i, file := range files {
        var err error
        bufs[i], err = ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading file %s: %v", file, err)
            return
        }
    }

    minLen := len(bufs[0])
    for _, b := range bufs[1:] {
        if len(b) < minLen {
            minLen = len(b)
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < minLen; i++ { 
        v := bufs[0][i]           
        for j := 1; j < len(files); j++ { 
            if v != bufs[j][i] {
                fmt.Printf("first difference at offset %[1]d = %#[1]x\n", i)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("no differences found")
}
```

---

Code should be readable. Drop references to `os.Args`; It's `files`.

For example, unreadable code and messages:

```
if len(os.Args) < 3 {
    fmt.Println("expecting at least 2 arguments")
    return
}
```

and so on.

Readable code and messages:

```
files := os.Args[1:]
if len(files) < 2 {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "expecting at least 2 files")
    return
}
```

and so on.

Also, error messages go to `stderr`.

In Go, lengths are pre-calculated. Delete

```
nfi := len(os.Args) - 1
```

`nfi` is simply the efficient and meaningful `len(files)`.

Why is it so complicated to read file data?

```
    fi, err := os.Open(fn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening file %s: %v", fn, err)
        return
    }
    defer fi.Close()

    bufs[i], err = ioutil.ReadAll(fi)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error reading from file %s: %v", fn, err)
    }
```

Note: `defer fi.Close()` doesn't work the way you want it to. The `defer`s don't run until `main` returns.

Simplify, just `ReadFile`,

```
    var err error
    bufs[i], err = ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading file %s: %v", file, err)
        return
    }
```

You wrote

```
    if l < min {
        min = l
    }
```

It's more readable to line them up

```
    if min > l {
        min = l
    }
```

I found the variable name `min` a little terse. I used `minLen`. And, again, `l := len(b)` is redundant. `len(b)` is pre-calculated.

```
// get a minimum len of all the buffers
min := len(bufs[0])
for _, b := range bufs[1:] {
    l := len(b)
    if l < min {
        min = l
    }
}
```

became

```
minLen := len(bufs[0])
for _, b := range bufs[1:] {
    if minLen > len(b) {
        minLen = len(b)
    }
}
```

You write:

```
fmt.Printf("first difference at offset %d = 0x%x\n", i, i)
```

Why `0x%x`?

Why  `i, i`?

Using the `fmt` package documentation:

```
fmt.Printf("first difference at offset %[1]d = %#[1]x\n", i)
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfectly clear. Line up `min > l` is most surprisingly pleasant.